# Batch renaming of shapefiles using ArcPy and folder name where shapefile is stored?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy

I am very new to Python and wondered if anyone had any idea how to do this?

I have ~100+ shapefiles named 'land boundary' within the folder of their site name.

Is this possible using Python in ArcGIS?

Comment: If you just want to replace a few characters in the name, or change the name in a standardized way, have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636996/replace-or-delete-certain-characters-from-filenames-of-all-files-in-a-folder) question.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  If the Q&Q @Martin linked to does not do what you are looking for, then be sure to edit your Question to provide more details about precisely what you are wanting to do with ArcPy.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure exactly what you want. I've prepare two scripts, I supose you want one of this, maybe with a little variation.

Having this file structure:

```
C:\test\foo\bar.dbf
C:\test\foo\bar.sbn
C:\test\foo\bar.sbx
C:\test\foo\bar.shp
C:\test\foo\bar.shx
```

**Script 1**:

Renames the files in the same folder.

```
import os
import ntpath

# Replace with your folder
path = "C:/test"

for root, dir, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        dirname = ntpath.basename(root)
        ori = root + '/' + file
        dest =  root + '/' + dirname + file
        os.rename(ori, dest)
```

Result:

```
C:\test\foo\foobar.dbf
C:\test\foo\foobar.sbn
C:\test\foo\foobar.sbx
C:\test\foo\foobar.shp
C:\test\foo\foobar.shx
```

**Script 2**:

Renames the files in the parent folder.

```
import os
import ntpath

# Replace with your folder
path = "C:/test"

for root, dir, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        parentdir = os.path.dirname (root)
        dirname = ntpath.basename(root)
        ori = root + '/' + file
        dest =  parentdir + '/' + dirname + file
        os.rename(ori, dest)
```

Result:

```
C:\test\foobar.dbf
C:\test\foobar.sbn
C:\test\foobar.sbx
C:\test\foobar.shp
C:\test\foobar.shx
```

**NOTE**: Both scripts renames every file under the specified path, not only shapefiles.

Comment: Thank you very much: I'll let you know how I get on with this when I;ve worked out how to add this code as a script

Comment: How to add folder name at suffix. I tried out but it got added "Folder name" after file extension?

Comment: Change line [dest =  root + '/' + dirname + file] to [dest =  root + '/' + (dirname + '.').join(file.split('.'))]